Geopointe Maps Export CSV Dataset data along with Shape Data?
Is it possible to export a CSV that has both data set information and the shape layer information?
The end goal is to have a spreadsheet that counts the number of contacts in each ward.
https://imgur.com/a/QoN50Nx
For example, I have the Chicago Wards shape layer along with Contacts dataset layer. If I export as CSV, it gives me the following columns:
|| || |Record Id|Object Name|Data Set Name|Jigsaw Contact ID|Address|Latitude|Longitude|Geocode Quality|

But I also want another column which tells me the Ward that the contact belongs in.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  If this data is in your Geopointe objects, you'll have to check with the vendor's support.
